# Why a method I call from another page doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have one method in the first page and I want to call this method from another page:

```
public async Task FavoritesForecast()
    {
        string FavoriteName = Preferences.Get("FavoriteName", "default_value");

        _cityEntry.Text = FavoriteName;
     }
```

From another page I call this method with this code:

```
async void BtnRead_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPersonId.Text))
        {
            //Get Person
            var person = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync(Convert.ToInt32(txtPersonId.Text));
            if (person != null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Success", "City Name: " + person.Name, "OK");

                Preferences.Set("FavoriteName", person.Name);

                var forecast = new AboutPage();
                _ = forecast.FavoritesForecast();

                var tabbedPage = this.Parent.Parent as TabbedPage;
                tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[1];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Required", "Please Enter ID in the field which is located under the name", "OK");
        }
```

But when refer me to the other page, the name in the search engine does not change?

Comment: this is async method. Show be called   await  forecast.FavoritesForecast();

Comment: You are creating a new AboutPage, use that method to set a field there, and then forget about it

Comment: as @HansKeﬆing points out, you are creating a **new instance** of `AboutPage` instead of using an existing instance.